# How to add label next to elements of circular floating action menu?

Tags: android, label, floating-action-button

I added circular floating action menu to my app but I can't find anywhere option to add label to elements. Can some has any idea how to add text?

I used this tutorial:
http://androidlift.info/2015/10/12/create-floating-action-button-fab-android/

Answer (score 4):

Circular floating menu can be created easily in [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout). `layout_constraintCircle`, `layout_constraintCircleAngle`, `layout_constraintCircleRadius` this property of  `ConstraintLayout` will help you to create circular positioning of views.

Check [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout#CircularPositioning) official documentation.

- `layout_constraintCircle` is for the id  of the center view
- `layout_constraintCircleAngle` is for the angle of the circular positioning view
- `layout_constraintCircleRadius` is for the radius of the circle.

  **This is a sample xml code for Arc menu:**

  ```
  <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context=".CircularPositioningActivity">
  <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fabMenu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu_white_24dp" />

  <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fabAttachFile"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:layout_constraintCircle="@id/fabMenu"
    app:layout_constraintCircleAngle="270"
    app:layout_constraintCircleRadius="100dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_attach_file_white_24dp"
  />

  <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fabAudio"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:layout_constraintCircle="@id/fabMenu"
    app:layout_constraintCircleAngle="315"
    app:layout_constraintCircleRadius="100dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_audiotrack_white_24dp" />

  <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fabCamera"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:layout_constraintCircle="@id/fabMenu"
    app:layout_constraintCircleAngle="0"
    app:layout_constraintCircleRadius="100dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_camera_alt_white_24dp" />

  <android.support.constraint.Group
    android:id="@+id/group"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:constraint_referenced_ids="fabAttachFile,fabCamera,fabAudio"

  />

  </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
  ```

  **This is how it look like**

  [image: Arc Menu]

> can't find anywhere option to add label to elements

You can replace each circular positioning views with viewgroup or different layout for adding multiple view. This is the easiest way to do with out any library.